# How to handle failed Matlab constructor?

Tags: matlab

The Matlab [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/using-objects-to-write-data-to-a-file.html) give an example of a class which closes a file if the object is deleted.  I'm trying something similar with the serial port object, but if my constructor fails to get a valid handle to the object, its `delete` method will necessarily throw an error.

So my question is how to make something like this:

```
classdef Filewriter < handle
   properties (Access = private)
      FileID
   end

   methods
      function obj = Filewriter(filename)
         obj.FileID = fopen(filename,'a'); % if this fails...
      end

      function writeToFile(obj,text_str)
         fprintf(obj.FileID,'%s\n',text_str);
      end

      function delete(obj)
         fclose(obj.FileID); % then this will also fail
      end
   end
end
```

...where the constructor may fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor you should check for the failure. In your case by comparing the `FileID` to `-1` and calling `error`. In the `delete` method check the `FileID` against `-1` as well, and do not perform the `fclose`, if it is `-1`, so it will perform cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a serial port object, you can do something like this in your classdef and constructor:

```
...
properties
  sp % serial port object
end

methods
  function obj = SerialPort(portID)
    sp = serial(portID);
    try
      fopen(sp)
    catch
      % Opening serial port failed. Do something to handle this. 
    end
  end
end
...
```

The key is to use try-catch block, so that the error thrown by "fopen" will not crash your program and you can still do something to remedy the situation if possible.

Comment: I think fopen is not throwing exceptions in matlab...(just tried it..)

Comment: @EugeneSh. If it is a valid COM (serial) port ID, it is not going to throw an error. However, if it is an invalid COM port, it will throw an error, at least on my computer.

Comment: I've checked against non-existent file.